# Error using Typescript Electron and ES6 modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, electron

The error:

```
App threw an error during load
D:\git\dynasty\build\electron-index.cjs:1
export {};
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1185:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1227:27)
    at Object..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1326:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:32)
    at node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:967:12
    at Function._load (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:2:13377)
    at loadApplicationPackage (D:\git\dynasty\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\default_app.asar\main.js:121:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\git\dynasty\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\default_app.asar\main.js:233:9)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1271:14)
```

My electron-index.cjs file is completely empty. I did not put any `export {};` into it.

If I change `"type": "module"` to `"type": "commonjs"` and change `electron-index.cjs` to `electrion-index.js` then `npm run electron` will succeed, but the executable emitted from `npm run make` will fail because I use import and I "Cannot use import statement outside a module", presumably because setting `"type": "commonjs"` makes it think it should use require.

Why is it adding an empty export to my .cjs file?

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "dynasty",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Dynasty",
  "main": "build/main.js",
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.7.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf ./build",
    "build": "tsc",
    "postbuild": "copyfiles -u 1 src/*.min.js src/index.htm src/style.css art/* art/**/* ./build",
    "electron": "electron ./build/electron-index.cjs --inspect",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "electron-forge start",
    "package": "electron-forge package",
    "make": "electron-forge make"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "",
  "bugs": {
    "url": ""
  },
  "homepage": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@electron-forge/cli": "^6.4.2",
    "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "^6.4.2",
    "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "^6.4.2",
    "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "^6.4.2",
    "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "^6.4.2",
    "@electron-forge/plugin-auto-unpack-natives": "^6.4.2",
    "copyfiles": "^2.4.1",
    "electron": "^26.2.1",
    "http-server": "^14.1.1",
    "rimraf": "^5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  }
}
```

and tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom", "es2017"],
    "module": "es2022",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "moduleResolution": "node10",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "build",
    "verbatimModuleSyntax": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "forge.config.js"
  ]
}
```